# Duplicate type name exception in System.Reflection.Emit when debugging in VisualStudio

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, code-first, reflection.emit, proxy-classes

My project uses Code First Entity Framework (Version 6).
My entity classes implement navigation properties as virtual properties.
This must mean that EF built proxy classes using ReflectionEmit.
**This works fine if I execute the application normally. But when I debug my project in VisualStudio (2013), I get an exception** (when executing the first request) explaining that there is a conflict in the creation of a type. 
Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType)
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
```

Is there a reason that Reflection.Emit does not work in the same way in this context compared to a standard execution?

Comment: I have the exact same problem...have you found a solution yet?